# Using VLC player activex within excel vba as a registration-free COM

Tags: excel, vba, vlc

Problem definition

I have two usb microscope reading part and serial numbers.
I want to control the display and recording of screen shots from Excel-VBA.

I would like to try this using the supplied VLC active X component.
I need the finish product to be a single zip that does not need to be installed.
I think using this activex object as a registration-free COM is the way to go.

References

I have been doing my homework, here are my references.

[How to use vlc.dll without registration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280623/how-to-use-vlc-dll-without-registration)

[Registration-Free COM Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1h056h.aspx)

[VLC Player and Excel Visual Basic Editor](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/baec16d1-e85c-4be9-8751-966bef527756/vlc-player-and-excel-visual-basic-editor?forum=isvvba)

[Cannot get registration-free COM working from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503117/cannot-get-registration-free-com-working-from-vba)

My attempt so far.

I created
Desktop\excel vlc demo\excel vlc demo.xlsb
I then copied the entire vlc distribution to Desktop\excel vlc demo\vlc\

This includes axvlc.dll and [axvlc.dll.manifest](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8907053)

I created a module and put this code in.

```
Sub VLC()
    Dim actCtx As Object
    Set actCtx = CreateObject("Microsoft.Windows.ActCtx")
    actCtx.Manifest = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\vlc\axvlc.dll.manifest"

    Dim myVlC As Object
    Set myVlC = actCtx.CreateObject("AXVLC.VLCPlugin2")

    myVlC.Visible = True
    myVlC.playlist.Add (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\demo.mov")
    myVlC.playlist.Play

End Sub
```

This fails at the line

```
    Set myVlC = actCtx.CreateObject("AXVLC.VLCPlugin2")
```

with error

```
    Run-time error '429':
    ActiveX component can't create object
```

It is possible I have the wrong object name "AXVLC.VLCPlugin2", I could not confirm if it is still valid in the [documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/).

It could also be that "user1610015" is correct in saying that "I don't think you can make reg-free COM work in this case"

At this point I am out of ideas, I never tried reg-free COM before so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong with the reg-free COM or the axvlc part !

thanks

EDIT 1: Attempt with early binding

I went in tool -> references, then clicked browse and added the axvlc.dll file.
I modified the code as follows (the AXVLC.VLCPlugin2
 part auto-completed so at least this part should work)

```
Sub VLC()
    Dim myVlC As New AXVLC.VLCPlugin2
    myVlC.Visible = True
    myVlC.playlist.Add (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\demo.mov")
    myVlC.playlist.Play

End Sub
```

However this fails with the same error

```
    Run-time error '429':
    ActiveX component can't create object
```

on the line

```
myVlC.Visible = True
```

Perhaps I also need to register this file with regsrv32 ?
EDIT 2:  tried regsvr32

ran this command from the vlc subfolder

```
regsvr32 axvlc.dll
```

I got a msgbox saying this command ran successfully, however I get the same error.

Comment: It simply doesn't work with late binding.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39176974/4088852) for the explanation.

Comment: I tried early binding, I tried to register with regsvr32 (it succeeded) however I get the same error (see updated question text).

Comment: That's bizarre. You actually don't need to register it if you add a reference BTW.  I almost wonder if the the `AXVLC.VLCPlugin2` isn't creatable. Now I'm going have to download and install it...  :-P

Comment: OK, installed and played with.  I can't replicate the issue though - the code runs just fine. It appears to need a host window though.

Comment: Did you run the installer or just used the files from the zip ?  What do you mean by a host window ?  I created a UserForm and ran this code but I get "invalid class string" 

  Set myVlC = UserForm1.Controls.Add("AXVLC.VLCPlugin2", "test1", True)

Comment: I ran the installer.  It lets me *try* to add it as a UserForm control, but that gives an unspecified error.  When I try to add it as a Worksheet control it crashes Excel.  It's apparently pretty tweaky.  Check out [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/baec16d1-e85c-4be9-8751-966bef527756/vlc-player-and-excel-visual-basic-editor?forum=isvvba).  Most of the recommendations I've run across are to use the legacy `VLCPlugin` interface instead of the `VLCPlugin2` interface, but I can't get the `addTarget` method to take any input.

Comment: ^^^ That link has the same error you're getting BTW.

Comment: if using late binding for vlc activex, you should not use "AXVLC.VLCPlugin2". instead use "VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"

Comment: I know i'm late with this, but... have you seen this: [Resolved - VLC ActiveX Control](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?622179-RESOLVED-VLC-ActiveX-Control) ?

Answer (score 1):

I had problems using VLC with Excel inserting vlc player onto a sheet and form.

It worked last year...
the "VLC Activex Plugin...." was not in the additional controls box to select.
Registering the dll was successful but still did not work.
Then I remembered i upgraded VLC to new version and 64Bit

I uninstalled VLC 64
and installed new version 32 bit
the "VLC Activex Plugin...." was Now in the additional controls box all good

Answer (score 0):

```
Set vlcControl = Controls.Add("VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2", "vlcControl")

vlcControl.Height = Me.Height
vlcControl.Width = Me.Width
vlcControl.Visible = True

Set vlcPlayer = vlcControl.object

vlcPlayer.playlist.Add ("rtsp://")
vlcPlayer.playlist.play
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**